# serilog minimumlevel override not working for console but does for rolling file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have the following code which successfully only logs Information logs that exclude Microsoft and other system ones, but the console still gets some info written to it which I would like to exclude

```
  "Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": { "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}] {Level:u3} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" }
  },
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "log-{Date}.log",
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff z}] {Level:u3} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  }
]
```

},

Also here is what gets written to console but not the rolling file based on above settings

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
  Entity Framework Core 2.0.1-rtm-125 initialized 'CryptoAlertContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
  Executed DbCommand (26ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [x].[CoinId], [x].[Icon], [x].[LastPriceBtc], [x].[LastPriceUsd], [x].[LastUpdated], [x].[Name], [x].[Rank], [x].[Symbol]
  FROM [Coins] AS [x]
  ORDER BY [x].[Rank]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing [`UseSerilog()`](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/08/use-serilog/) in your program start-up code: the console output you've show is from the default ASP.NET logging provider, not the Serilog one.

Comment: your right
I had the following


            // add logging
            serviceCollection.AddLogging(x =>
            {
                x.AddDebug();
                x.AddConsole();
                x.AddSerilog();
            });
 i removed the first 2 lines and only left addserilog (I am not using asp.net, i am using .net core console)